# Discord bot kick function problems

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord function and one of the features I wish to implement is kick and it responds when you are either not an admin or you are trying to kick an admin, the code I wrote works for kicking people, but it stops working altogether when I try putting in the responses.

Here's the code so far-

```py
@bot.command(name='kick')
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
    if user.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} is an admin')
    else:
        await user.kick(reason=reason)
        kick = discord.Embed(title=f"Kicked {user.name}!", description=f"Reason: {reason}\nBy: {ctx.author.mention}")
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=kick)
        await user.send(embed=kick)
```

Comment: Does it raise any error?

Comment: Could you be more specific with your issue and what you tried? I've tested you're code and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if else statements doesn't match the question, to kick person it should have admin rights and if it has the admin rights but isn't kicking cause according to your code only people without admin rights can kick the users...

**The correct code should be**

```
@bot.command(name='kick')
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
    if user.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await user.kick(reason=reason)
        kick = discord.Embed(title=f"Kicked {user.name}!", description=f"Reason: {reason}\nBy: {ctx.author.mention}")
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=kick)
        await user.send(embed=kick)
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} is not an admin')
```